# How can I install a ShiVa3D app on an iPhone? (for development testing)

Tags: iphone, ios, shiva3d

I'm new to ShiVa3D (a 3d games engine).

I'm testing a very simple app that just displays a 3D model, it works in ShiVa Editor (1.9 PLE). I can export it fine as a .stk file. All this is on a Windows PC.

I then open the ShiVa3D Authoring tool (v1.1) on Mac OS X. I create and build my XCode project, but when I go to test the application on a device it fails with the error:

`CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.2'`

I've tried changing the project plist and setting the Code Signing Identity - with no change in the error.

Has anyone managed to install a ShiVa3D app on an iPhone (or any iOS device?). I'm not trying to publish to the App Store, I just want to test my app on a device.

Comment: Daniel, yes I have, I can deploy any project I create through XCode without Shiva3d.

Comment: Can someone please add Shiva3D as a tag?   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ShiVa_(game_engine) it is a fairly new game engine

Comment: Many thanks donkim for the shiva3d tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer after some Googling:

http://www.stonetrip.com/developer/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=22104&p=28476&hilit=signing+identity#p28476

Here are the details that helped

1. Load the Authoring Tool, and click on "Get Started Now"
2. In the "Application Pack" blank under "Content", navigate to a .stk you exported from the editor hit "Next."
3. Now under "Authoring," select "Project" and enter your bundle and signing info. **DO NOT HIT THE "BUILD" button, instead click on the "Build" Heading at the top.
4. Now set the build type to "Development." Hit Build.**
5. Your project should now open up in XCode where you will have to Edit Project and Target settings to reflect the proper SDK and Code Sign Identity.
6. Build and Run the project and it should deploy to your iPhone!